# get cat id is not working from custom taxonomy

Tags: categories

I have a custom taxonomy "city". I am having a hard time to get cat id. the number.
It's also custom post type "job"

This works only for default category under the default post.

```
  $provinceID = get_cat_ID($cityname);
  echo "<br/>bb=".$provinceID."<br/>";
```

I have found this one but it's not also working as well.
the function name was get_cat_ID and it caused an error. so I have changed name.

```
  function get_cat_ID11( $cat_name='$cityname' ) {
$cat = get_term_by( 'name', $cat_name, 'category' );
if ( $cat )
    return $cat->term_id;
return 0;
  }

  echo get_cat_ID11;
```

How can I get the cat id from custom taxonomy , custom post type?

Answer (score 1):

I have just found the solution.

I just miss to put a taxonomy name.

```
     $cat = get_term_by( 'name', $cat_name, 'city' );
```

this works fine!

Thanks,